# Issue with setIgnoreWhitespace in XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I'm having trouble getting xmlunit to ignore whitespace in my XML using setIgnoreWhitespace... any idea what could be wrong or what I could check?

JVM: 1.6, XMLUnit 1.3, IDE: JDeveloper 11.1.1.6

For example the below returns "Expected number of child nodes '2' but was '1'".  If I take out the extra space it passes.

```
@Test
public void testExample()  {
    String inputXML = "<test><innertest>data</innertest></test>";
    String expectedResultXml = "<test> <innertest>data</innertest></test>";

    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true);

    try {
        assertXMLEqual("Did not match!!", expectedResultXml, inputXML);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must have some incompatible XML library in my classpath. Overriding the JAXP libs as below resolved the issue (also added xerces and xalan jars).

```
    XMLUnit.setControlParser("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
    XMLUnit.setTestParser("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
    XMLUnit.setSAXParserFactory("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
    XMLUnit.setTransformerFactory("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit you expected that any whitespace characters is to be ignored but that is just not the case for that setting.

See [`XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace`](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/XMLUnit.html#setIgnoreWhitespace(boolean)):

> Whether to ignore whitespace when comparing node values.
>
> [...]
>
> Setting this parameter has no effect on whitespace inside texts.

This setting does not mean that whitespace-only text-nodes will be removed (and not checked for). It will only mean that the whitespace is ignored when comparing the node values of the `<test>` elements. But that test didn't cause the message. In your case a check for the count of child-nodes did raise the message.

See [3.8.1. Whitespace Handling](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s03.html#Comparing:%20Configuration) for a more detailed description and more configuration options (e.g. `XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace`).

Comment: But <test> is not a text, it contains <innertest> node?  Anyway code below resolved the issue, so pretty sure that was it...

Comment: No, <test> contains a children that is a textnode (that space). As that textnode is expected, it's looked for. You might want to report this as a bug, too, because according to the docs it must not be expected with the JAXP libs.

Answer (score -1):

Overriding the JAXP libs as @user392909 did, did not succeed for me.

But a conflict with another library in my project was the root cause. First I changed the import order of some libraries which finally fixed the test. So I was able to identify the conflicting library. It was j2ee.jar.

I removed it (and had to replace it by tomcat-catalina.jar,  tomcat-juli.jar and javamail.jar to resolve upcoming compilation errors).

The import order doesn't matter any longer since j2ee.jar was removed / replaced and the xml diff is now working as expected.